# Can't format question properly because of character limit

Tags: discussion, support, editing, formatting

I have a problem with editing this question:
[Upgrade to 18.04, now sudo apt-get upgrade produces loads of insserv errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063455/upgrade-to-1804-now-problem-w-sudo-apt-get-upgrade)

OP didn't format the terminal output (which as you can see, is really long), so I just used the *preformatted text code* option as I usually do, but there is a problem. After adding the formatting, the number of characters is over the 30,000 limit, and I've got something like 30 840, so all around 840 more than accepted.

I removed some parts of the output (which I replaced with `[...]` with a note at the bottom to explain), and I would like to know if there is a better way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed an annoying problem.

I think your edit removing some parts of the output which were unnecessary was fine. It was also a good idea to leave a note of what you had removed, because anything you've taken out will always be available in the revision history. I handled your edit suggestion and I actually removed those parts because I don't think they had any useful information in them anyway (but maybe I was overzealous).

This problem also occurs when formatting output from scripts like the wireless info script and boot repair info. Output that is too long can be dumped in a pastebin such as [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com), but it's always preferable to have the information in the post if possible.

The reason the automatic pre formatting makes the output too long is that it inserts 4 space characters before each line. This adds *lines**4 characters to the count. As a workaround, you can use html tags:

```
<pre><code>lines of formatted text
go here
between the tags</code></pre>
```

This works without indenting, so you don't need to add 4 spaces per line.

However, you need to check the text, because within these tags, other html tags will still work, instead of rendering literally. For example...

Indenting shows tags:

```
<i>indented words</i>
```

The syntax `<pre><code><i>preformatted words</i></code></pre>` prints this, when not indented:

```
preformatted words
```

So check the text for anything that may cause unexpected text formatting when doing this (obviously it's great when you actually want to add formatting).

Comment: If only SE would implement [fenced markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks), it would almost solve this issue completely :(

Comment: @Dan [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks)